# View Twitter feed without seeing @ replies?

Tags: twitter, yahoo-pipes

There were a number of sites out there that did this via Yahoo Pipes - such as [noReplies](http://www.sixteenseven.com/noreplies/)

**Now that it appears that Yahoo Pipes is [banned from accessing Twitter data](http://www.quora.com/Has-Twitter-banned-Yahoo-Pipes-from-accessing-its-servers), are there any other options?**

I'd like to be able to link to my Twitter feed without @ replies - both as a clickable link, and ideally an RSS feed

Comment: Dupe of question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619773/filter-out-replies-in-a-twitter-feed

Comment: It would be more correct to say related than a duplicate. Also one is asking to filter the feed specifically, the other is asking how to display it on their site.

Comment: looks like it may have been a false alarm, as Pipes is able to access Twitter again...

Answer (score 1):

So there is not native support for this request but it can be achieved with the help of some plugins and since you were already talking about Yahoo Pipes I am sure this will not be overly intimidating.

The plugin is called TweetFilter and is a "Twitter Filter for Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE 8+"

One of the called out features is

> Option filter replies to me also hides matching posts from other users directed to you (in case they match the searching criteria).

a full  list of the features and capabilities is here http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/49905

install instruction vary by browser view them all here http://tweetfilter.netne.net/

*on a side note i use this plugin myself and its pretty awesome.*

Comment: sadly this is a browser plug in and not a webapp...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, webapp solution as previous answer was browser plugin solution.

Hootsuite!

Full customizable feeds setup for how you want to consume them, you can even create RSS feeds about of them.

There are both free and paid plans. 
http://hootsuite.com/plans